# How to include a page template and template part into my plugin

Tags: plugin-development, template-include

I am creating my first plugin with a template for the frontend.

My current structure is:

> /my_plugin/views/page_templates

I have 2 main issues I am trying to resolve

1. Is this the best way to include a template
2. How to include external files into template using get_template_part()

The template code:

```
function mbbp_frontend_page_layout($page_template) {
    global $post;
    
    if ( is_page("bookings") ) {
        
        $page_template = MBBP_BOOKING_PLUGIN_DIR_PATH . '/views/page-bookings.php';
        
    }
    return $page_template;
}
add_filter("page_template", "mbbp_frontend_page_layout");
```

And then, within `page-bookings.php` I have included:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'page-templates', 'payment-form' ); ?>
```

The get_template_part() code is not including anything so I am assuming it is because of the way my template is included in the plugin but as this my first plugin, I do not know how to better handle this.

Comment: Note that `get_template_part()` only searches in the theme folders (child theme and parent theme), so if you want to load a template in your plugin folder, you could just use `include` for example.

Comment: @SallyCJ that was my assumption, thanks for clarifying.